# Is there any such thing as "for suppose"?

Tags: word-usage

I have heard a few people using **for suppose** to give an example or any hypothetical scenario like:

> For suppose we start early tomorrow we'll reach home before noon.

I have a strong feeling that's not correct and could simply be replaced with just **Suppose**, **For example** or even **if**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the standard form would be:

- **Suppose we start early tomorrow, we'll reach home before noon** which means "I suggest we start early in order to get the benefit of reaching home before noon"
- **If we start early tomorrow, we'll reach home before noon** which means "This action has this effect".  This might be positive or negative, and could be used as a suggestion for leaving early or not.  The difference would be in the context -- do we know that reaching home before noon is good or bad?